# Materialize - DropDown onclick disappear Issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, material-design

I am using below HTML which is a `Dropdown`. On clicking the Menu Icon the DropDown pops up perfectly but doesn't disappear on clicking the Icon again.

If I click else where on the page, the `Dropdown` disappears.

```
<nav style="position: fixed;">

            <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
            <a href='#' data-activates='dropdown1' id="mainMenu" class="menu-dropdown">
                <i class="mdi-navigation-menu"></i>
            </a>

           <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
            <div id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content container'>
                <div class="row icon-container">
                    <div class="col s4 center-align">
                        <i class="mdi-action-dashboard"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 center-align">
                        <i class="mdi-action-perm-phone-msg"></i>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s4 center-align">
                        <i class="mdi-action-perm-scan-wifi"></i>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
</nav>
```

----- Added

```
$('.menu-dropdown').dropdown({
                inDuration: 300,
                outDuration: 225,
                constrain_width: false, // Does not change width of dropdown to that of the activator
                hover: false, // Activate on hover
                gutter: 0, // Spacing from edge
                belowOrigin: true, // Displays dropdown below the button
                closeOnClick: true
            });
```

How to disappear the Dropdown on Icon Click?

Comment: can you create fiddle for our reference

Comment: I have this problem, solved with updated materialize.js and materialize.min.js .

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#mainMenu').on('click',function(){
 $('#dropdown1').toggle();
})
```

Comment: Pls see my edited question...i am using `.dropdown({})` to initialize the DropDown.

Answer (score 1):

This is without the use of jQuery

```
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <a href='#' onclick="toggleMenu('dropdown1')" data-activates='dropdown1' class="menu-dropdown">
        <i class="mdi-navigation-menu">erer</i>
    </a>

   <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
    <div id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content container'>
        <div class="row icon-container">
            <div class="col s4 center-align">
                <i class="mdi-action-dashboard">ffse</i>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 center-align">
                <i class="mdi-action-perm-phone-msg">fsefs</i>
            </div>
            <div class="col s4 center-align">
                <i class="mdi-action-perm-scan-wifi">fsefs</i>
            </div>
        </div>

    <script>
        function toggleMenu(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);
            if (e.style.display == 'block' || e.style.display=='') {
                e.style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                e.style.display = 'block';
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: This would be doing same behaviour without using jQuery